# Server Error as java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException while deploying

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

```
I am getting below error while trying to deploy war file in wildfly 22. 

Pom.xml



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
    <relativePath />
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.mmm</groupId>
  <artifactId>AppRecomGIT</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>AppRecomGIT</name>
  <description>Application Engineering User Management</description>
  <version>1.0.6-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.release.version>3.0.0-M1</maven.release.version>
    <maven.compiler.version>3.8.1</maven.compiler.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <github.global.server>github</github.global.server>
    <maven.surefire.version>3.0.0-M5</maven.surefire.version>
    <!-- <junit.version>5.6.2</junit.version> -->
    <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>
  </properties>

  <!-- for autogenerating github tag -->
  <scm>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:https://github.com/3mcloud/appEngRecommender-User-Mgmt-Docker</developerConnection>
    <!-- <tag>HEAD</tag> -->
    <tag>HEAD</tag>
  </scm>

  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>${github.global.server}</id>
      <name>appEngRecommender-User-Mgmt-Docker</name>
      <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/3mcloud/appEngRecommender-User-Mgmt-Docker</url>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.956</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${maven.release.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <!-- <finalName>AppEnggUserMgmt</finalName> -->
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
      </plugin>
      <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
      <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.1</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
          <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.2</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.2</version>
      </plugin>
      <!-- <plugin> Paul - this is a great plugin but damn noisy
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <configLocation>google_checks.xml</configLocation>
          <consoleOutput>false</consoleOutput>
          <failsOnError>false</failsOnError>
          <violationSeverity>warning</violationSeverity>
          <failOnViolation>false</failOnViolation>
        </configuration>
      </plugin> -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>report</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>check</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <rules>
                <rule>
                  <element>CLASS</element>
                  <excludes>
                    <!-- <exclude>nothing</exclude> use to exclude in the future -->
                  </excludes>
                  <limits>
                    <limit>
                      <counter>LINE</counter>
                      <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                      <minimum>0.75</minimum>
                    </limit>
                  </limits>
                </rule>
              </rules>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven.release.version}</version>
        <configuration>
        <tagNameFormat>v@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
        <checkModificationExcludes>
        <checkModificationExclude>pom.xml</checkModificationExclude>
        </checkModificationExcludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>

The stacTrace is below:
```

8:07:44,924 ERROR [org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 102) Application run failed: java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException: Mismatch of count of formal and actual type arguments in constructor of groovy.lang.Closure: 0 formal argument(s) 1 actual argument(s)
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.validateConstructorArguments(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:59)
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:52)
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.make(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:100)
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeParameterizedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:105)
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:140)
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.ConstructorRepository.computeParameterTypes(ConstructorRepository.java:111)
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.ConstructorRepository.getParameterTypes(ConstructorRepository.java:87)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Executable.getGenericParameterTypes(Executable.java:289)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.getGenericParameterTypes(Method.java:328)
at java.desktop/java.beans.FeatureDescriptor.getParameterTypes(FeatureDescriptor.java:391)
at java.desktop/java.beans.MethodDescriptor.setMethod(MethodDescriptor.java:118)
at java.desktop/java.beans.MethodDescriptor.(MethodDescriptor.java:74)
at java.desktop/java.beans.MethodDescriptor.(MethodDescriptor.java:58)
at java.desktop/java.beans.Introspector.getTargetMethodInfo(Introspector.java:1028)
at java.desktop/java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:443)
at java.desktop/java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:195)
at deployment.AppRecomGIT-1.0.6-SNAPSHOT.war//groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl$15.run(MetaClassImpl.java:2940)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:554)
at deployment.AppRecomGIT-1.0.6-SNAPSHOT.war//groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.addProperties(MetaClassImpl.java:2938)
at deployment.AppRecomGIT-1.0.6-SNAPSHOT.war//groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.initialize(MetaClassImpl.java:2921)
at deployment.AppRecomGIT-1.0.6-SNAPSHOT.war//org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClassUnderLock(ClassInfo.java:166)
at deployment.AppRecomGIT-1.0.6-SNAPSHOT.war//org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClass(ClassInfo.java:182)
at deployment.AppRecomGIT-1.0.6-SNAPSHOT.war//org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.getMetaClass(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:210)
at deployment.AppRecomGIT-1.0.6-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.groovy.GroovyBeanDefinitionReader.(GroovyBeanDefinitionReader.java:150)
at deployment.AppRecomGIT-1.0.6-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:90)
at deployment.AppRecomGIT-1.0.6-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createBeanDefinitionLoader(SpringApplication.java:747)
at deployment.AppRecomGIT-1.0.6-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.load(SpringApplication.java:690)
at deployment.AppRecomGIT-1.0.6-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:413)
at deployment.AppRecomGIT-1.0.6-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:325)
at deployment.AppRecomGIT-1.0.6-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:173)
at deployment.AppRecomGIT-1.0.6-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:153)
at deployment.AppRecomGIT-1.0.6-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:95)
at deployment.AppRecomGIT-1.0.6-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:174)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:204)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:187)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@22.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@22.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@22.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@22.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@22.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@22.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:255)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@22.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:96)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@22.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)

18:07:44,927 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 102) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."AppRecomGIT-1.0.6-SNAPSHOT.war".undertow-deployment: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."AppRecomGIT-1.0.6-SNAPSHOT.war".undertow-deployment: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException: Mismatch of count of formal and actual type arguments in constructor of groovy.lang.Closure: 0 formal argument(s) 1 actual argument(s)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@22.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:81)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException: Mismatch of count of formal and actual type arguments in constructor of groovy.lang.Closure: 0 formal argument(s) 1 actual argument(s)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:257)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@22.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:96)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@22.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException: Mismatch of count of formal and actual type arguments in constructor of groovy.lang.Closure: 0 formal argument(s) 1 actual argument(s)
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.validateConstructorArguments(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:59)
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:52)
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.make(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:100)
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeParameterizedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:105)
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:140)
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.ConstructorRepository.computeParameterTypes(ConstructorRepository.java:111)
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.ConstructorRepository.getParameterTypes(ConstructorRepository.java:87)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Executable.getGenericParameterTypes(Executable.java:289)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.getGenericParameterTypes(Method.java:328)
at java.desktop/java.beans.FeatureDescriptor.getParameterTypes(FeatureDescriptor.java:391)
at java.desktop/java.beans.MethodDescriptor.setMethod(MethodDescriptor.java:118)
at java.desktop/java.beans.MethodDescriptor.(MethodDescriptor.java:74)
at java.desktop/java.beans.MethodDescriptor.(MethodDescriptor.java:58

Please let me know if further details needed I believe there is some issue with the jars which are causing this issue not sure.

Thanks,
Manohar